# How do I inspect values and fields while developing a greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Probably a very silly question, but I'm trying to make a simple thing like this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='pattern'");
for (var J = links.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var link  = links[J];
    let myvar = "foobar";
    link.href = `https://example.com${myvar}`
}
```

This is just simple text replacement, and the above code works in the sense that it does replace the links.

But what I find a mess is that my development feels so much like just trial and error. I modify the code. If nothing happens on the page when I update, then I know that's something is wrong. But this is extremely inefficient. My procedure is something like trying code like this:

```
var myvar=link.text;
alert(myvar);
```

Then I update the page. If nothing shows up at all, then link probably didn't have a field called text. I realize that people developing greasemonkey scripts for certain are doing this in a much more efficient manner, via a console or something. But I just cannot figure out where to start. How would I approach the above? How to figure out available fields and methods in an object? How to inspect their values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your code ...

*Updated based on comment*

```js
// To view logged message, open Developer tools for THAT page 
// e.g. F12 in Firefox/Chrome

const myvar = 'foobar';

// get the target links
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="pattern"');
console.log('links', links);

// run a loop on the links
links.forEach(a => { 
 
  console.log('link url before change', a.href);
  a.href = 'https://example.com' + myvar
  console.log('link url after change', a.href);

  // if you need link text
  console.log('link text', a.textContent);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not about that. It's about how to debug in general.